# Play Audio file and play over SIP

Tags: java, audio, sip, jain-sip

I have created a SIP call, right now I dont have any sound to it i.e. I dont have a Sound Manager. I would like to play a Audio file for the Receiver instead. i.e. When I make a call to someone, I want them to hear the Audio message. How do I send the file and make it play?

```
 ContentLengthHeader contentLength = headerFactory.createContentLengthHeader(211);
 ContentTypeHeader contentType = 
     headerFactory.createContentTypeHeader("application", "sdp");

 String sdpData = "v=0\n" + 
                "o=test 795808818 480847547 IN IP4 "+localIP+"\n" + 
                "s=Audio Call\n" + 
                "u=/audio/play.wav"+
                "c=IN IP4 "+localIP+"\n" + 
                "t=0 0\n" + 
                "m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 0 8 101\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\n" + 
                "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\n" + 
                "a=sendrecv";

byte[] contents = sdpData.getBytes();        
request.setContent(contents, contentType);
```

If I directly send the file like this will it play? Also is it possible to send text and play it over the call?

Comment: Please try something first, then ask a question.

Comment: can you suggest me the direction which I can follow for this implementation?

Comment: `For the transmission of media streams (voice, video) the SDP payload carried in SIP messages typically employs the Real-time Transport Protocol (RTP) or the Secure Real-time Transport Protocol (SRTP).` You don't "send" audio nor video with SIP.

Answer (score 1):

SIP is used only for signalling ie call setup, to play an audio file you need to instruct a Media Server to do that. I would recommend avoiding going to the lower layers and use a simple API to do that. [RestComm](https://github.com/Mobicents/RestComm) would allow you to do that. There is even a docker image now http://www.telestax.com/docker-image-for-mobicents-restcomm-7-3-0/. 
RestComm comes with a number of preconfigured demos, the one playing a wav file is tied to the number 1234 see how to test it here http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-testing-default-demos/